# What is the proper search syntax for BlobServiceClient.FindBlobsByTags?

Tags: .net, azure, f#, azure-storage

I'm attempting find blobs in a container on my local dev machine, using [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio), with [`BlobServiceClient.FindBlobsByTags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.findblobsbytags) but cannot figure out the proper syntax for the search clause. Below is the code I'm using.

```ml
#r "nuget: Azure.Storage.Blobs"

open Azure.Storage.Blobs
open System

let connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage")

let serviceClient = BlobServiceClient(connectionString)

let searchClause = "@container = 'reports'"

// returns a 400 error
let results = serviceClient.FindBlobsByTags(searchClause)
```

Here's the error I get back from the repl:

```
> results;;
val it: Azure.Pageable<Models.TaggedBlobItem> =
  Error: Service request failed.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Headers:
Server: Azurite-Blob/3.15.0
Date: Fri, 28 Jan 2022 15:48:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: REDACTED
Content-Length: 0
```

I can successfully list containers when I run the [`BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.getblobcontainers?view=azure-dotnet) method.